# How does USB communications work in a mouse?

Tags: usb, mouse, cable, wired-networking

My Logitech M-UAE96 USB mouse is working properly except for the left button, which does not register all clicks I make and is even more finicky when I try to keep it pressed (drag and drop is hard to do because it releases immediately, and even when single-clicking the pressure is so intermittent that it registers as multiple clicks).

Having seen that the mouse works fine if I remove the top cover, I guess there's a broken wire in the cable and the cover pinches on it in a way that pulls apart the two sections of the broken wire.

I would have guessed that there was a wire dedicated to the left click and that it was the damaged one, but this makes no sense: there are way more inputs than wires and it's USB so the 5 wires must be ground, power +/- and data +/-.

So I thought the pinching might only happen while the left button is pressed, but everything else keeps working properly (fluid cursor movement, scrolling, right clicks, middle clicks...) even if I keep the left button pressed down.

What is happening?

I am probably going to shorten the cable by a few inches and reconnect the wires as soon as I am back at work and I have the tools to crimp the wires back into the connector, but I would like to understand where the problem is first.

Comment: Dirty (or oxidized) contacts is the likeliest cause of an intermittent button/switch. "*I would have guessed that there was a wire dedicated to the left click ...*" -- No, your simplistic scheme was never used for PC mice. USB requires a microcontroller on the device end, so there are only 4 wires: power, ground, and a (twisted) pair for half-duplex differential data signals. The communication is bi-directional.

Comment: The problem is most likely inside the mouse; a mechanical button that has wear or is oxidized (inside).

Comment: @Hannu the mechanical button being worn or oxidized was my first guess, but it works properly and very well whenever the mouse cover is absent.

Comment: @sawdust that looks like the start of a good answer, but also consider the fact that the mouse works very well without the cover. Why?

Comment: @Zachiel -- You're over-analyzing this. If the problem is not the contacts, then what could be the cause? It's certainly not the USB cable or USB connector! A bug in the mouse microcontroller firmware? Focus first on the likeliest cause before looking elsewhere. It's so easy and cheap to clean contacts that eliminating the likeliest cause is more prudent & faster than trying to resolve every discrepancy. BTW I use an [industrial-strength contact cleaner](https://www.circuitspecialists.com/801b-100ml.html) (rather than just alcohol) which might improve my success rate with a quick cleaning.

Comment: @sawdust I have tried again and again. The problem is only present while the mouse is properly closed. The cover is just plastic. The problem is not in the electronics, unless the plastic somehow messes with the electronics (pushing something it shouldn't, pinching, bending, making shifting some electronic component out of its contact, etc.). I'm starting to suspect that pressing the button puts pressure on the cable or on some different contacts and it somehow disrupts the communication. I can't reproduce the problem with the mouse open. I can't see what happens when it's closed.